# Liferay: Get URL in portal.normal.vm from properties file

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay

I have problems to read info from properties file "liferay-portal-6.1.0/tomcat-7.0.23/lib/myweb-application.properties" in portal_normal.vm
myweb-application.properties:

```
redirect.docs.url = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

"liferay-portal-6.1.0/tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/web-theme/templates/portal_normal.vm":

```
 #set ($docsURL =  $propsUtil.get("redirect.docs.url"))  <a href="$docsURL">#language("foot.docs")</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PropsUtil (or $propsUtil) accesses `portal.properties`, typically configured through `portal-ext.properties`. So unless you add your myweb-application.properties as an "external properties" file, PropsUtil won't find it.

One way to do this is to add this line to your `portal-ext.properties`:

```
  include-and-override=/path/to/myweb-application.properties
```

but make sure it's not using the same keys as `portal.properties` for different purposes.

Comment: Is there any way to access this file without editing "portal-ext.properties"?

Comment: Yes, but you can't use `com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PropsUtil`, which is exactly for accessing `portal(-ext).properties`. Velocity is a very thin layer around Java, you can basically use all kinds of other methods (e.g. through `java.util.Properties') to read external data.

Answer (score 1):

Get value of portal-ext.properties

eg. test.name="sachin"

```
${propsUtil.get("test.name")}
```